# Check for NAs in `RasterLayer` and plot them in different colour

Tags: raster, r, sf, masking

I know it's an easy question. But how can I find out whats the distribution of my `NA-Values` to non `NA`-Values? And how could I plot my raster normally and make the NA values appear in a different colour than just plain white?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the distribution of NA/non-NA, use `table` on the values of the raster.

Test raster:

```
> r = raster()
```

Fill with 1 to N:

```
> r[] = 1:ncell(r)
```

Set some cells to NA:

```
> r[sample(ncell(r),ncell(r)/5)]=NA
```

To count NA/non-NA, use `table`:

```
> table(is.na(r[]))

FALSE  TRUE 
51840 12960
```

To plot this with NA in red, do:

```
plot(r, colNA="red")
```

Comment: where do you have all this knowledge from haha 
Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Example data

```
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)
```

Count the cells that are NA (1, TRUE) or not-NA (0, FALSE)

```
freq(is.na(r))
     layer value count
[1,]     1     0  4608
[2,]     1     1  3942
```

It is best to avoid the use of `[]` with raster data, except for with small toy datasets, as it is not memory-safe.

Plot the NAs with a different color

```
plot(r, colNA="red")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe useful to notice that summary(r) actually provides the numbers of NA's as well. And since ncell(r) provides the total count. Ratio is readily available.